# Is there a way to recover google drive API logs?

Tags: logging, google-drive-api

I maintain an application that logs data to a google spreadsheet via the Drive API. Recently the sheet that the data was logged to was accidentally deleted. The data in the sheet was inconsequential, but the data that was supposed to be logged is important.

My question is whether google keeps any logs of the data sent to the Drive API and if I can recover it.

A google search didn't turn anything up, but I thought that I would ask here to see if anyone knows for sure.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### The two kind of data that can be recovered with Google Drive (API) are

1. **Version history, see [here](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308971?hl=en)**

- This helps if you accidently deleted / overwrote the contents (not deleted the whole file).
- If you trashed your file, it is not deleted - you can restore it.

2. **Restore data from the Admin console as explained [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6052340?hl=en)**

- If the deletion took place less than 25 days ago, you can either restore the data yourself (provided you are an admin) or ask the admin to do it for you.
- To restore data, go from the Admin console on `Users` and then right-click on `More` and `Restore data`
- You can specify the period for which all deleted data shall be restored.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the data that I want wasn't deleted, it was never logged to begin with. It was sent via the API, but it was trying to insert it into a sheet that no longer exists.

Comment: Why do you not try make the same request to the API again? I am sorry if I do not understand the question correctly - please explain which API "sent" you which kind of data.

Comment: The data is not logged by the application. It was about a month's worth of data that was being sent from the application and received by the google API, but not actually being entered into the spreadsheet. It seems likely to me that the data is lost, but I thought I would ask to see if there are any logs of such requests kept by google.

Comment: Unfortunately from Google's side there is no stored data about failed requests to its APIs, not even about successful requests (if the request is successful, the data simply gets written into the sheet). So if at all, the information only can retrieved from your application's side.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is the info I needed. I knew it was a long shot.